# split string using IFS example

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i wrote a sample script which will split the string into multiple variable

```
#!/bin/bash
IN="One-XX-X-17.0.0"
IFS='-' read -a ADDR <<< "$IN"
for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do
    echo "${ADDR[i]}"
done

while IFS='.' read -a ADDR[3]; do
      for i in "${ADDR[3]}"; do
           process "$i"
done
```

like var11 = One, var12=XX, var13=X, major1=17, minor1=0, rel1=0

but while running this script every time getting error .
Could someone tell me what wrong with my script

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: it was showing this below error i don't know why                                           
./versionsplit.sh: line 3: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device
./versionsplit.sh: line 8: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
IN="One-XX-X-17.0.0"
IFS='-' read -a ADDR <<< "$IN"
for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
#split 17.0.0 into NUM
IFS='.' read -a NUM <<<${ADDR[3]};
for i in "${NUM[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

output:

```
One
XX
X
17.0.0
17
0
0
```

**UPD**

```
#same code
#array of names of variable
var=(major minor rel)

#split 17.0.0 into NUM
IFS='.' read -a NUM <<<${ADDR[3]};

for((i=0;i<${#NUM[@]};i++)); do
    #assign
    eval ${var[$i]}=${NUM[$i]}
done
#now test
echo $major
echo $minor 
echo $rel
```

output:

```
17
0
0
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but the output looks like this 
    One
    XX
    X
    17.0.0
    17 0 0

Comment: You mean on one line?, then replace `echo "$i"` with `printf " %s" "$i"` (or `echo -n " $i"`) and add `echo ""` after `done`.

Comment: still no success , this is not an issue could you tell me after execution of below block 
`code` #split 17.0.0 into NUM
IFS='.' read -a NUM <<<${ADDR[3]};
for i in "${NUM[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done                                                                                                     how do assign the output to different variable like 
Major = 17 
Minor = 0
Rel = 0

Comment: updated answer.